# Unable to remove images from iphone 6

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

My Iphone storage is almost full, so I am trying to copy and remove images from my iphone to pc with itunes. For some reason I am not able to do that and the reverse is happening.
Images from my laptop is copied to my iphone.

How should I fix that?

Comment: What PC OS are you using?  Windows? Mac?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes won't actually transfer pictures from your iPhone to your laptop. To do that, you will need to use the built-in Windows Image Capture program. It should open as an option when you plug your iPhone into your computer. After starting the program you can import the pictures from your iPhone.

Here is Apple's official documentation on importing photos: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302

These steps may be more concise:
http://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/best-ways-get-photos-iphone/